# JS/ CSS Matrix cube with axis scale

Tags: javascript, css, matrix, css-transforms

I have this code that generates the div.
By applying the css transform property using matrix, I would to get the three faces of a cube, aligning the div properly.
The problem is in the left div. Setting array leftArr scale (d * scale), I can not align vertically correctly div left side of the top div.
Can anyone tell me the best way to get a simulation of a cube.

Thank you.

---

CSS:

```
.face {
        height: 50px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        width: 50px;
      }
```

JS:

```
var angle = 45,
    r = parseFloat(angle) * (Math.PI / 180),
    cos_theta = Math.cos(r),
    sin_theta = Math.sin(r);

var a = cos_theta,
    b = sin_theta,
    c = -sin_theta,
    d = cos_theta;


var face = 50, //reference to .face class
    k = 0,
    j = 100; //constant

var scale = 3;
var dX = face * Math.SQRT2 * scale;
var dY = face * Math.SQRT2;


for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){

    var tx = j + k;
    var ty = j;
    var lx = j + k - dX/4;
    var ly = ty;

    var topArr = [a * scale, b, c * scale, d, tx, ty];
    var leftArr = [a * scale, b, 0, d * scale, lx, ly];

    var top = 'matrix(' + topArr.join(',') + ')';
    var left = 'matrix(' + leftArr.join(',') + ')';

    k += dX;

    $('<div/>', {
                 id : 'top_'+i,
                 'class' : 'face',
                 css : {
                         'background' : 'hsla( ' + parseInt(Math.random() * 90) + ', 100%, 50%, 0.5 )',
                         'transform' : top
                       }
                 }).appendTo('body');

     $('<div/>', {
                  id : 'left_'+i,
                  'class' : 'face',
                  css : {
                          'background' : 'hsla( ' + parseInt(Math.random() * 90) + ', 100%, 50%, 0.5 )',
                          'transform' : left
                         }
                  }).appendTo('body');                    
}
```

Example:

Scale = 1

[image: Scale = 1]

Scale = 2

[image: Scale = 2]

Scale = 3

[image: Scale = 3]

---

UPDATE:

After some test with:

```
var ly = ty + dY/2 + ( ( (dY/2)*(scale-1) ) / 2);
```

the code take sense, but if there are better solution, any help is appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

You are using 2d transforms to rotate in 3d.
If you want an elegant solution, you should use 3d matrices, that are of dimension 4.
Then you would have the left side come from a 90 degrees turn from the down side; and the same translation would be applied to that.

If you want to use 2d transforms, then the best way to go would be to precalculate the 2 d transforms for each face. Then calculate the translation matrix for all the cube (only 1 matrix, you are moving all faces at the same time). The matrices for each face will the product of the translation matrix and the face matrix. (keep in mind that this is not conmutative, the order is important)

Comment: Yes ok, i know 3d matrix. This would be a test to make a "pseudo" 3d cube using only 3 faces (top, left, right), and make it transform in perspective "visual effect", for example translation in x-axis (stretch x) or z-axis. I use 3 faces only because i must replicate the "cube" many times, and the browser have some problem to render many faces of many "cubes". By the way, the above test works (not well but works) if you add right face simple copy and translate the left face. The problem is when you change the angle value... Thanks to the help!!!